# Switching scenes don't retain maximized screen in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scene

### My configuration:

- I need to **switch between scenes** via the same stage
- I need to **keep a maximized stage** that fills the whole screen

### My issue:

- although I set my stage to be maximized `primaryStage.setMaximized(true);`it **adopts its size to the size of the scenes** afterwards.

### What I tried until now:

- I tried using `primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(<the root node of scene>)`. While it worked to keep the stage maximized, yet after each change of scene the focus on the previously focused gui control is lost (after switch only the first gui control in the scene hierarchy is focused). I really need scenes, so that any gui control that was focused still be will focused after the stage changes its scene.

### I need your assistance:

- I really need your assistance in keeping the stage maximized during changing scenes.

### Here is my example code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NewFXMain extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // init buttons
    Button btn1 = new Button("switch to next scene >>");
    Button btn2 = new Button("<< switch to previous scene");

    // first scene
    StackPane root1 = new StackPane();
    root1.getChildren().add(btn1);
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(root1, 300, 250);

    // second scene
    StackPane root2 = new StackPane();
    root2.getChildren().add(btn2);
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2, 500, 400);

    // button actions
    btn1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
    });
    btn2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1); 
    });

    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### SOLUTION

> create scenes depending on the screen size of your monitor

after several attempts I finally figured how to easily solve this problem to keep the maximized screen while retaining the focused node on each Scene. Hope it helps the community:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NewFXMain extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // get screensize of monitor
    Rectangle2D screenSize = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

    // init buttons
    Button btn1 = new Button("switch to next scene >>");
    Button btn2 = new Button("<< switch to previous scene");

    // first rootNode
    StackPane root1 = new StackPane();
    root1.getChildren().add(btn1);
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(root1, screenSize.getWidth(), screenSize.getHeight());

    // second rootNode
    StackPane root2 = new StackPane();
    root2.getChildren().add(btn2);
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2, screenSize.getWidth(), screenSize.getHeight());

    // button actions
    btn1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
    });
    btn2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    });

    primaryStage.setMaximized(true); // keep this since otherwise the titlebar is bit overlapped
    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Working on this problem as well. Swapping scenes creates good isolation and is preferred. Swapping panes adds complexity. If so, ensure all child panes are cleared for all scenarios.  Our solution was similar to yours. Our app would set the minX & minY position of the new Scene to the center of the screen. We attempted to set the JavaFX.Window x and y to the screen zero but this is ignored when Window.setScene invalidates. The final solution is simple. Use myStage.setX(n) to 0 in the same class that creates the stage, after the stage.setScene(newScene, screenWd, screenHt) has been called.

Comment: As a note. On mac, the myStage.setMaximized(true) was ignored after setScene(...) was called for the new scene. Even if we attempted to set it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug.  You can report it at: http://bugreport.java.com.

In the meantime, as a workaround, you probably need to just set the pane for a shared scene, replacing its content rather than replacing the scene.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NewFXMainFixed extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // init buttons
        Button btn1 = new Button("switch to next scene >>");
        Button btn2 = new Button("<< switch to previous scene");

        // first scene
        StackPane root1 = new StackPane();
        root1.getChildren().add(btn1);

        // second scene
        StackPane root2 = new StackPane();
        root2.getChildren().add(btn2);

        // button actions
        btn1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> 
                primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(root2)
        );
        btn2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> 
                primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(root1)
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(root1);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Jewelsea! It's a blessing for having someone this experienced to answer my question. I tried your solution before but the setRoot() method has one serious flaw, which always will put the focus on the first gui element in the root node hierarchy. Since I mostly will be using the keyboard to navigate through my app, I need each scene to remember which gui control was last focused on. (also the use of <gui_control>.requestFocus()  has no effec with the setRoot() method). Is there any possibility to solve the focus issue with setRoot()? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try remembering what control was focused before you change the root.  Not sure how you determine what has focus (you might need to loop through the scene nodes).  Once you know what it is you could save it in [userData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData-java.lang.Object-) for the root node.  Then, once you switch roots, look up the user data in the new root and call requestFocus on that node.  Sometimes you need to wrap the requestFocus call in Platform.runLater for it to take effect, it is a little quirky.  Didn't try it, but I think it will work.

Comment: Yes, I can see where you are heading. It indeed is a little quirky to implement although I hoped there might have been an out-of-the-box solution. Nevertheless I definitely will make it work with your suggested idea. In the meantime I will report this as a bug to the oracle team. After that I will implement the setUserData() method and append it to this post as the temporarily solution in hope it might benefit other with the same need. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Hi Jewel, I tried to implement your suggestion but the saving the focused node is a pain. Besides since I am using afterbunerFX, the <node>.requestFocus() seems not be working when the rootNode is not focused. Anyways I was able to figure out a different approach in that I create Scenes depending on the ScreenSize, this way I don't need to fiddle with the focusNode things. I added a solution.